# Only show loading spinner on long requests

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to get a loading spinner to only display on requests greater than 200 ms. I thought I had it working, but it seems the events are fired out of order somehow.

This is from my `loading-spinner.js` class:

```
class LoadingSpinner {
    constructor(milliseconds) {
        this.timeoutId = null;
        this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
    }

    waitForLongRequest() {
        this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('waiting for long request');
            console.log(this.timeoutId);
            document.body.classList.remove("loaded");
        }, this.milliseconds);
    }

    cancel() {
        console.log('canceling long request');
        console.log(this.timeoutId);
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
        document.body.classList.add("loaded");
    }
}

export default LoadingSpinner;
```

This is from my `app.js`:

```
import LoadingSpinner from './custom/loading-spinner.js';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    var ls = new LoadingSpinner(200);

    Livewire.hook('message.sent', (message, component) => {
        console.log('message.sent fired');
        ls.waitForLongRequest();
    });

    Livewire.hook('message.processed', (message, component) => {
        console.log('message.processed fired');
        ls.cancel();
    });
});
```

Here's the output from my console. The last request causes the spinner to show indefinitely.

[image]

Comment: your LoadingSpinner only supports one request. In your example, 2 short requests are sent, generating 2 timeout ids, but only the last one was kept in LoadingSpinner (the second timeoutId will override the first one). Both requests were processed before the 200ms, and the cancel was only called on the last timeout id. Resulting in the first timeout still being executed => thus the infinite loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @user3252327 comments, this is the fix:

```js
waitForLongRequest() {
    if (this.timeoutId) {
        this.cancel()
    }
    this.timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('waiting for long request');
        console.log(this.timeoutId);
        document.body.classList.remove("loaded");
    }, this.milliseconds);
}
```

Update: And for good measures we should reset `this.timeoutId` after cancel:

```
cancel() {
    console.log('canceling long request');
    console.log(this.timeoutId);
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);
    this.timeoutId = null;
    document.body.classList.add("loaded");
}
```